# Problema com ArrayList Android

Tags: android, imagem, listview, arraylist, get

Estou tentando criar um listView com imagens e estou recebendo esse erro e o app não roda.

**Stack do erro**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pedido.meu.telas_meu_pedido, PID: 5562
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.pedido.meu.telas_meu_pedido.ItemAdapter.getView(ItemAdapter.java:54)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2373)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2165)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:788)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20680)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2830)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2357)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1493)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7283)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5562 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

**ListaProdutosActivity.java**

```
package com.pedido.meu.telas_meu_pedido;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListaProdutosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ItemAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Integer> idImages;
    ArrayList<String> nameList;

    int ids[] = {R.mipmap.ic_acai};

    String names[] = {"AÇAÍ"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_produtos);
     //   String[] listaProdutos = {"Açaí", "Açaí", "Açaí", "Botijão de Gás", "Botijão de água", "Botijão de Gás", "Botijão de Gás", "Botijão de água", "Botijão de água"};
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.txListViewProdutos);

        idImages = new ArrayList<>();
        idImages = getList();
        nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        nameList = getNameList();
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(ListaProdutosActivity.this, idImages, nameList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(ListaProdutosActivity.this, "Item Id Is" + nameList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

 /*   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   cria um objeto do tipo MenuInflater, o qual é responsável por criar objetos do tipo menu, a partir de um
   arquivo xml
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        metodo que pega a referencia do arquivo xml e pega item por item e vai criando os MenuItem e adicionando no menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_simple_list_view, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    } */

    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getList ()
    {
        idImages = new ArrayList<>();
        /*    idImages.add(R.drawable.java);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.php);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.csharp);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.android);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.js);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.html);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.css); */
        return idImages;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNameList () {
        nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        nameList.add("AÇAÍ");
     /*       nameList.add("JAVA");
            nameList.add("PHP");
            nameList.add("C SHARP");
            nameList.add("ANDROID");
            nameList.add("JAVASCRIPT");
            nameList.add("HTML 5");
            nameList.add("CSS 3"); */
        return nameList;
    }

}
```

**Imagem.java**

```
package com.pedido.meu.telas_meu_pedido;

public class Imagem
{
    private int imageId;
    private String imageName;

    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }

    public void setImageName(String imageName) {
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }
}
```

**ItemAdapter.java**

```
package com.pedido.meu.telas_meu_pedido;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.pedido.meu.telas_meu_pedido.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listaId;
    private ArrayList<String> listaNome;
    public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> listaId, ArrayList<String> listaNome)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.listaId = listaId;
        this.listaNome=listaNome;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return listaNome.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return listaNome.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_item_produtos, null);
        }
        ImageView img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgListItemProduto);
        TextView tv =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtListItemProduto);
        img.setImageResource(listaId.get(position));
        tv.setText(listaNome.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**activity_lista_produtos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pedido.meu.telas_meu_pedido.ListaProdutosActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


                    <!-- Título da tela -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgListaProdutos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_lista_produtos_round"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txtTitleListaProdutos"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />

                    <!-- Lista de produtos -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/txListViewProdutos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>


**list_item_produtos.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgListItemProduto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_acai_round"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListItemProduto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgListItemProduto"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgListItemProduto"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgListItemProduto"
        android:text="TextView"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o Leonardo mencionou acima, o problema estava no trecho de código abaixo:

**ListaProdutosActivity.java**

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> getList ()
    {
        idImages = new ArrayList<>();
        /*    idImages.add(R.drawable.java);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.php);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.csharp);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.android);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.js);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.html);
            idImages.add(R.drawable.css); */
        return idImages;
    }
```

Resolvi o problema inserindo o seguinte trecho de código(para poder inserir a imagem que eu gostaria):

**`idImages.add(R.mipmap.ic_acai);`**

De modo que o código final do método ficou da seguinte forma:

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> getList ()
    {
        idImages = new ArrayList<>();
        idImages.add(R.mipmap.ic_acai);
        return idImages;
    }
```

Comment: boa hehe, sao pequenos detalhes que passam despercebidos e dar uma dor de cabeça

Answer (score 2):

Você está setando o setImageResource com um int, o seu getList nao está retornando nada alem de um array vazio.

Enquanto o seu getCount no seu adapter está levando em conta a quantidade de listaNome.size(); note que o array de id está vazio, enquanto o lista nome tem 1 elemento.

Recomento vc fazer carregamento de imagens dinâmicas, da internet. Conhece o Glide ou o Picasso? ótimas lib para carregar imagem;

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(listaNotificacoes.get(position).getUrlFotoPerfil())
            .into(imagemPerfil);
```

ou o link direto da imagem pra vc testar ai

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .load("https://i.imgur.com/SAVP4sO.jpg")
            .into(imagemPerfil);
```